What is the smallest full abstract family of languages containing $L_k = \{w^k\mid w \in \Sigma^\ast\}$? Is it multiple context-free languages?
A family of languages $\mathfrak{L} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(\Sigma^\ast)$ is called a full AFL if it is closed under union, concatenation, Kleene star, homomorphism, inverse homomorphism, and intersection with regular languages. For example, regular languages form a full AFL as well as context-free ones.
I wonder if there is a nice description of multiple context-free languages (mcfl's), i.e. of the languages generated by linear context-free rewriting systems, as a full AFL (consult the definition here: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.3115/981967.981979). It is known that mcfl's form a full AFL; however, I am interested in whether it is generated by some simple languages, for example, by $L_k =  \{\underbrace{w\ldots w}_{k~\text{times}}\mid w \in \Sigma^\ast\}$.
So, my question is: does the smallest full AFL containing all context-free languages and also all the languages $L_k$ coincide with the set of mcfl's?
Clearly, the former is contained in the latter since $L_k$ is an mcfl for each $k$. I have not found any result of such kind in the literature.
